# RealmConfiguration in other class

Tags: android, realm

I am having trouble in opening and writing realm files in my android code.

Below is example code.

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

        RealmConfiguration realmA = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("A.realm")
                .schemaVersion(1)
                .build();

        RealmConfiguration realmB = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("B.realm")
                .schemaVersion(25)
                .build();

        Realm.init(this);

        Realm realm_A = Realm.getInstance(realmA);
        // Do some jobs with realm_A
    }
}
```

I make two configuration named realmA and realmB for example instance. But, **I want to open them in another activity**, named `SecondActivity`.

I know `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` but, there is two configuration so, I cannot use `Realm.setDefaultInstance()`

---

You can say that declare realmA and realmB in `SecondActivity`. But, the problem is that I should modify RealmConfiguration every time after modifying schema like updating schemaVersion 1 to 2 etc. And that bother me.. :( (If there are tons of activities, I should modify tons of it..)

Is there any good way to use RealmConfiguration in other class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put configuration in Application class because will be created and available when the app in foreground.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private RealmConfiguration rca, rcb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // add configuration here
        // also init private variable of configuration
    }

    public RealmConfigurationA() {
       return realmConfiguration;
    }
}
```

And in your manifest file add

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    ....
```

To access your configuration, you can create a get inside `MyApplication` class and use it with a cast

```
RealmConfiguration rc = ((MyApplication) getApplicationContext()).getRealmConfigurationA();
```

Comment: Then how can I open realm file with RealmConfiguration? How can I handle instance?

Comment: Ummm.. Thank you I will check and test in my code. Thanks for reply :)